# Configuring Spring batch xml

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Issue: Using spring batch, i need to read a file which has todays date. E.g  test_02032015.txt.This file will be in a directory /test/example. Its an unix environment that i need to fetch file from.

question is how to configure spring batch xml so that above mentioned file is read

Any pointers to relevant website or solution would be of great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few ways to address a requirement like this:

1. If you don't need to worry about the other files in a directory, you can just use a wild card in the file name like this:

   `<property name="resource" value="data/iosample/input/*.xml" />`
2. Another alternative would be to pass the value into the job as a parameter and reference it like this:

   `<property name="resource" value="#{jobParameters['input.file']}" />`
3. Finally you could use SpEL to build the file name (Sorry I don't have an example of that handy).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. 
 I do have one more query, assuming that I read all the files from the folder say data/isosample/input/*.txt. However 
 I want my reader to process only that file in that input folder which has today's data i.e. test_02032015. How do I do that?. 
 Can I add that to JobParams as one of the params in the listener, so that reader refers to that?

Comment: Then you'll want to use option 2 or 3.